# Visual studio crashes during startup .NET Framework exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio, exception

Atmel Studio and Visual Studio can't startup because they keepcrashing. It get the following error from the Just-In-Time:

```
An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occurred in devenv.exe
```

The event viewer gives the following application error:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
Faulting module name: wpfgfx_v0400.dll, version: 4.6.1586.0, time stamp: 0x575a1a80
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x0009a84c
Faulting process ID: 0x2dcc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2471ebff929fc
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
Report ID: 4f78078f-ca40-45d7-b08b-d8cf8d73c529
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I tried to re-install all the .NET frameworks but nothing helped.

Comment: Do you use any extensions? Try starting in safe mode: `devenv.exe /SafeMode` and see if that works. If not, run a repair of your VS installation.

Comment: When I enter that command in cmd I see the loading screen but it crashed immediately and giving the same unhandled exception.

Comment: I already re-installed Visual Studio and repaired it but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use Method 2 to disable hardware acceleration,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894215